# How to resolve "bad interpreter: Permission denied" with #! /usr/bin/python3

Tags: python-3.x, centos7

I'm trying to use the `'#! /usr/bin/python3'` on a centos7 but since I had to 
install Python3 via:

```
Yum install centos-release-scl
Yum install rh-python36
scl enable rh-python36 bash
```

The Python3 isn't in the `/usr/bin/python3`

I tried using:
`#! /opt/rh/rh-python36`

I get these errors when trying to run a python script

```
bash: ./pw.py: /opt/rh/rh-python36: bad interpreter: Permission denied
./pw.py: /opt/rh/rh-python36: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

Comment: please do no run sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/rh/rh-python36/
it will delete make sudo command unusable

Answer (score 2):

This means your folder permissions are not allowing you to use that interpreter. Please verify that `/opt/rh/rh-python36` has it's permissions set so that you can read and execute there, otherwise it will give you a permission denied error.

`sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/rh/rh-python36/`

Comment: I tired that and verified the change took, see output.

drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 32 Apr 25 07:32 rh-python36

Let me know what you think, thanks.

Comment: Could you try running the script as root? It's possible the folder ownership my be funky and denying you access as a normal user.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, but not elegant fix: Try downloading a local user version of Python and reference that local Python3 file `#! /local/path/python3`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ vim /usr/bin/yum
```

in this file, edit it to

```
!# *****/bin/python2.7
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to use Python 2.